# Triple integral evaluation problem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am asked to evaluate the triple integral,
$$\iiint_E (12x^2-2yx-5) \ dV$$
Where $E$ is the region enclosed by the surfaces $$z=x^2-1, \ z=1-x^2, \ y=0, \ y=2$$
Am I right in saying that we can define the region;
$$E=\{(x,y,z)\ | \ -1\leq x\leq 1, \ 0\leq y \leq 2, \ x^2-1\leq z \leq1-x^2\}$$

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your region $E$ is correct but you have to think the order of the integration. First set the limits for $x,z$ (imagine the region in $xz$-plane) and then find the limits for $y$. The order of the volume integral is:
$$ \int_{y=0}^{2} \int_{x=-1}^{1} \int_{z=x^2-1}^{1-x^2} (12x^2-2yx-5) dzdxdy.  $$